# AzureAD Powershell list all available roles rather than assigned roles

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to figure out a user friendly way to assign roles for my Azure App Registration with Powershell.
`Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId 'XXXXX-X..'`
With this command I can get a list of all roles assigned to users.
I am not able to find a command that will just list the roles that exist whether they are assigned to someone or not.
Does this exist? I haven't found it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cmdlet you would want to use is [`Get-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) and then app roles will be available through its `AppRoles` property.

Please try something like:

```
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "ObjectId eq '<object-id of the app>'"
$appRoles = $app.AppRoles
$appRoles
```

Will produce an output like containing all roles:

```
AllowedMemberTypes : {User}                                                                                             Description        : Role description.
DisplayName        : Role name
Id                 : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
IsEnabled          : True
Value              : Role value
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, I could not use ObjectId though, but DisplayName and AppId works so that's great. :)